# PGSQL CTE recursive INSERT RETURNING autoincrement

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, auto-increment, recursive-query, sql-returning

**What I have:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.treeview_menu_node (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    parent_id int8 NULL,
    data jsonb NULL,
    name varchar NULL,
    caption varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT treeview_menu_node_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node
(parent_id, "name")
VALUES(NULL, 'node 1');

INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node
(parent_id, "name")
VALUES(1, 'node 1.1');

INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node
(parent_id, "name")
VALUES(1, 'node 1.2');

INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node
(parent_id, "name")
VALUES(NULL, 'node 2');

INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node
(parent_id, "name")
VALUES(4, 'node 2.1');

INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node
(parent_id, "name")
VALUES(4, 'node 2.2');
```

Structure:

- node 1

  - sub node 1.1
  - sub node 1.2
- node 2

  - sub node 2.1
  - sub node 2.2

**What I need:**

Copy node 1 into node 2 recursively

- node 1

  - sub node 1.1
  - sub node 1.2
- node 2

  - sub node 2.1
  - sub node 2.2
  - *NODE 1*

    - *SUB NODE 1.1*
    - *SUB NODE 1.2*

**What I try:**

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node (parent_id, name, caption, data)
        SELECT new_parent_id, name, caption, data
        FROM (
            SELECT tmn.id, tmn.parent_id, :parent_id::BIGINT new_parent_id, tmn.name, tmn.caption, tmn.data
            FROM public.treeview_menu_node tmn
            WHERE id IN (:ids)
        ) t
    RETURNING id, parent_id, name, caption, data
    UNION ALL 
    INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node (parent_id, name, caption, data)
        SELECT new_parent_id, name, caption, data
        FROM (
            SELECT tmn.id, tmn.parent_id, r.id new_parent_id, tmn.name, tmn.caption, tmn.data
            FROM public.treeview_menu_node tmn
            JOIN r r ON r.id = tmn.parent_id 
        ) t
    RETURNING id, parent_id, name, caption, data
)
SELECT id, parent_id, name, caption, data
FROM r;
```

Where:

- :parent_id is destination node id
- :ids is a list or one node to copy

**What I get:**

SQL Error [42601]: syntax error (Near: "UNION") Position: 357

---

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1e6fa/3

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want, but duplicating data is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Hello @LaurenzAlbe and thanks for the help.
I'm sure what I need to copy. The closest analogy: copying files in windows explorer.

Comment: Please describe **what** you are trying to accomplish, not just the sql for how you are trying it. What is the goal of those inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Multiple inserts in recursive CTE are not allowed. Instead of this, use the function:

```sql
NEXTVAL('table_sequensor_of_autoincrement')
```

The function returns a new id, like an `INSERT` command. Thanks to this, you can prepare the entire array for insertion using a single `INSERT` command.

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT tmn.id, NEXTVAL('treeview_menu_id_seq') new_id, tmn.parent_id, :parent_id::BIGINT new_parent_id, tmn.name, tmn.caption, tmn.data
    FROM public.treeview_menu_node tmn
    WHERE id IN (:ids)
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT tmn.id, NEXTVAL('treeview_menu_id_seq') new_id, tmn.parent_id, r.new_id new_parent_id, tmn.name, tmn.caption, tmn.data
    FROM public.treeview_menu_node tmn
    JOIN r r ON r.id = tmn.parent_id 
)
INSERT INTO public.treeview_menu_node (id, parent_id, name, caption, data)
SELECT new_id, new_parent_id, name, caption, data
FROM r;
```

---

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1e6fa/10